# How to hide items that don't fit in the grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid holding 6 items horizontally.

Each item has a minimum width of 200px.

If there is not enough space to fit an entire item, the item should be hidden.

Right now, when there is not enough space to fit an entire item, it is partially shown. Instead of being partially shown, how can I hide items that don't entirely fit in the grid.

Further explanation:

Each grid item is 200px.

If grid is 400px in width, only show 2 items and hide the rest.
When grid moves up to 600px in width, show 3 items and hide the rest...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use 'auto-fit' so that the grid wraps the elements and only the ones that fit are in the first line. If you want to hide the 2nd line you can add the following css to the parent container

'      overflow: hidden;
height: 75px;'

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
border: 1px solid red;
overflow-x: scroll;
grid-auto-flow: column;
grid-auto-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr);
width: 600px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would I have to add " height: 75px;" to hide the 2nd line?

Comment: so that the parent container is the height of only 1 image. Is that the result you were looking for?

Comment: instead of making the image wrap down. how would I make the image wrap to the right (horizontally).

Comment: i updated the answer see if that is the required result

Comment: Right on track. Now how would I hide the grid item if there is not enough space to display them entirely?

Comment: not sure what you mean , can you be more clear?

Comment: the `grid-template-columns` is useless and can be removed since you made the flow to be a column one and you defined the `grid-auto-columns`

Comment: Per OP the question "If there is not enough space to fit an entire item, the item should be hidden." this should not be the accepted answer since it adds a scroll bar rather than hide the items.

Answer (score 7):

Do it like below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr)); /* auto-fill here */
  grid-template-rows:auto; /* first row auto */
  grid-auto-rows: 0; /* all the other rows 0 */
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden; /* hide the overflow */
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="72" viewBox="135.5 361.375 200 72" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 135.5 361.375 200 72" xml:space="preserve" type="image/svg+xml"><title></title><path d="M159.23,431.966c-5.84-0.232-10.618-1.83-14.354-4.798c-0.713-0.567-2.412-2.267-2.982-2.984
c-1.515-1.905-2.545-3.759-3.232-5.816c-2.114-6.332-1.026-14.641,3.112-23.76c3.543-7.807,9.01-15.55,18.548-26.274
c1.405-1.578,5.589-6.193,5.616-6.193c0.01,0-0.218,0.395-0.505,0.876c-2.48,4.154-4.602,9.047-5.758,13.283
c-1.857,6.797-1.633,12.63,0.656,17.153c1.579,3.116,4.286,5.815,7.33,7.307c5.329,2.611,13.131,2.827,22.659,0.632
c0.656-0.152,33.162-8.781,72.236-19.176c39.074-10.396,71.049-18.895,71.054-18.888c0.011,0.009-90.78,38.859-137.911,59.014
c-7.464,3.191-9.46,3.997-12.969,5.229C173.76,430.721,165.725,432.224,159.23,431.966z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a pretty neat solution for me. Especially these two:

`grid-template-rows:auto; /* first row auto */`
`grid-auto-rows: 0; /* all the other rows 0 */`

Comment: My observation with CSS is what @temaniAfiF posts is "pretty neat" :)